# Using sudo commands in Cocoa and Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, privileges, sudo

What is the proper way to run something like `$sudo touch folder_name` or `$sudo rm` from within Objective-C/Cocoa? I'm changing and moving around a few files and need elevated privileges. Any code sample would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to `sudo` in iPhone?

Comment: sorry my mind was wandering. I replaced the tag with 'mac'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to do it is `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()`, but that's discouraged for the normal course of things.  Mainly it's for installers, I gather.

Something like:

```
AuthorizationRef auth = NULL;
OSStatus err = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed, &auth);
err = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(auth, command, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, args, NULL);
```

And you add appropriate checking of `err`...

See the [Authorization](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/Reference/reference.html) documentation.

Comment: This is sadly no longer supported, but you can use an AppleScript to execute shell with elevated privileges.

Comment: Or use `NSXPCConnection`

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this. Which one you choose depends on what you want to do. The simplest and unsafest way is to simple set the s-bit on an extra helper tool that you call from your code and does what needs admin rights. Take a look at the [BetterAuthorizationSample](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/BetterAuthorizationSample/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004207) for the most fancy and complicated way of executing privileged code.

The [Authorization Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html) gives you all you need.

Comment: “The simplest and unsafest way is to simple set the s-bit on an extra helper tool that you call from your code and does what needs admin rights.” That's actually the way Apple recommends. You're supposed to use `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` only to confer the setuid bit on the helper tool. The idea is to confine root powers to only the code that needs powers (the task-specific helper tool), so that code that doesn't need powers (your app) doesn't have them. It's the Principle of Least Privilege.